# Docker: "unrecognised option '-p'"

Tags: docker

Running a docker container ...

```sh
docker run --name mongodb -d mongo:3.4-xenial --expose 27017
```

Results in the error "Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '-p'" in the log.

However, moving the `--expose` parameter to the left works fine:

```sh
docker run --name mongodb --expose 27017 -d mongo:3.4-xenial
```

I don't understand why, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `docker run` [syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) is: `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]`, everything you're passing after the `IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST]` is being passed as `[COMMAND] [ARG...]` to the `ENTRYPOINT` of the container.

A `docker inspect mongo:3.4-xenial --format {{.Config.Entrypoint}}` shows the `ENTRYPOINT` as `docker-entrypoint.sh` (e.g. you're essentially trying to execute `docker-entrypoint.sh --expose ...`).

You can trace the execution i.e.: `docker run --name mongodb --entrypoint bash mongo:3.4-xenial -c "bash -x docker-entrypoint.sh --expose 27017"`

```
+ set -Eeuo pipefail
+ '[' - = - ']'
+ set -- mongod --expose 27017
+ originalArgOne=mongod
+ [[ mongod == mongo* ]]
++ id -u
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ '[' mongod = mongod ']'
+ find /data/configdb /data/db '!' -user mongodb -exec chown mongodb '{}' +
+ chown --dereference mongodb /proc/1/fd/1 /proc/1/fd/2
+ exec gosu mongodb /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mongod --expose 27017
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--expose'
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

`docker run --name mongodb --expose 27017 -d mongo:3.4-xenial` is passing `--expose 27017` in the `docker run` `[OPTIONS]`.

Comment: Makes sense, and pretty obvious now that it's been said. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Docker run doc:

> Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

So:

```
docker run --name mongodb -d mongo:3.4-xenial --expose 27017
```

`--expose` is `COMMAND` (or entrypoint parameter) for container in this case (and it doesn't look like a valid command for mongo)

But:

```
docker run --name mongodb --expose 27017 -d mongo:3.4-xenial
```

`--expose 27017` is `OPTION` for `docker run` command in this case