# Can't get --env-file to load local .env into docker run

Tags: docker, environment-variables

Basically trying to load a local `.env` file during `docker run` with the following:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 2f92a663d532 --env-file ./.env
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "--env-file": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I've read the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file), but I'm not using `ubuntu` and have tried a number of variations with the same result.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY requirements*.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "--log-level", "info", "config.wsgi:application", "-t", "150"]
```

How should I go about loading these local `.env` env vars during `docker run` not using `docker-compose`?

Comment: [Everything passed after the `[IMAGE]` is passed as the `[CMD]` to the containers `[ENTRYPOINT]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57699847/1423507). Run the container i.e. `docker run -p 8080:8080 --env-file ./.env 2f92a663d532`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "unrecognised option '-p'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699708/docker-unrecognised-option-p)

Comment: @masseyb `docker run -p 8080:8080 --env-file ./.env 2f92a663d532` resolved the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`docker run -p 8080:8080 --env-file ./.env 2f92a663d532` resolved the issue.